# Problem with starting Steam on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: steam

I've recently installed Ubuntu, and tried installing steam. It wouldn't start so naturally I went "Google has the answer", and it had. My problem is this: this line won't run.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

It tells me this when I enter it: `dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture`.

Answer (score 0):

The version of APT in 12.04 is slightly older than the time they fixed multiarch support. Your error is because of the version of APT not supporting multiarch properly. That guide only, as far as I know, works on 12.10 and newer.